# Cuando creo un Controlador, no me aparece la Clase de contexto de datos, ¿como lo puedo arreglar?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

cuando intento crear un controlador no me deja asignarle de donde va a tomar los datos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Descubrí que en la clase de la base de datos (perdón las palabras que estoy usando, espero que se entienda) estoy usando IdentityDbContext

```
    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext
    {
```

y si lo reemplazo por DbContext se soluciona,

```
    public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
    {
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero me deja de andar toda la parte de usuarios. ¿Como se puede corregir esto?

Comment: Has intentado cambiar a `IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>`?

Comment: estuve probando, no recuerdo si lo use, pero acabo de probarlo y me dice que **"el nombre del tipo o espacio de nombres 'ApplicationUser' no se encontró"**

Comment: Cree la clase 'ApplicationUser' y la cambie en todo el proyecto, probé que funcione todo correctamente, compila bien. pero sigo sin poder agregar un Controlador de MVC con vistas que usan Entity Framework.